# C++ compiler error - 'No matching function for call...'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to ascertain the reason behind this compiler error which is 'No matching function call to address::set_street(); Any advice would be much appreciated - thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    class address {

    public:

        address();

        void set_street(string street) {
            streetname = street;
        };


        string  get_street() {
            return streetname;
        };  


        void    set_parish(string parish) {
            parishname = parish;
        }

        string  get_parish() {
            return parishname;
        }

        void    set_country(string country) {
            countryname = country;
        }

        string  get_country() {
            return countryname;
        }


    private:
        string streetname;
        string parishname;
        string countryname;
    };


    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

        system("color 0c");

        address enteredaddress;

            cout<<"Enter street name" <<endl <<endl;

        cin >>enteredAddress.set_street();

        cout<< endl;


            system ("pause");

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: One solution would be to get rid of the tired getters and setters, make `streetname` a `public` member, and say `cin >> enteredAddress.streetname;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how the I/O works in C++: you cannot read from a stream and pass the result to a setter like that. You need to read the street into a variable first, and then pass that var to set_street:

```
string tmpStr;
cin >> tmpStr;
enteredAddress.set_street(tmpStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`set_street()` requires an argument, it's looking for one without any parameters and it can't find one that's why it's complaining.

You need to store the input in a string variable and then call the method with that string as a parameter.